# Is it possible to install a package that contains only one component of Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui

Material-UI is a very big package and I only want to use one component of it.

Is there a way to install a package that only contains the component I want to use?

e.g.

use

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
```

But only have in your `package.json` something like `@material-ui/core/Button`.

The reason I want this is to have a small `node_modules`.

Answer (score 9):

you can install each component of Material-UI via bit.dev collection:
https://bit.dev/mui-org/material-ui
Here is the Button component for example:
https://bit.dev/mui-org/material-ui/button

I exported the project to [bit.dev](http://bit.dev) and I'm trying to keep it up to date as much as possible.

Comment: Is it still working? I tried to install some packages but none works

Comment: Is it free? I can't figure it out and when I try to sign up I get an error. When I try to install I get a 404 so I guess it no longer maintained.

Answer (score 2):

You can install and use the isolated material components here:
[bit.dev](https://bit.dev/)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to care about the size of the `node_modules` folder.
"The bundle size will NOT increase if you install the entire MUI package but just import one single component.

In fact, I can install every single node modules in npm without using a single import statement and my bundle size will not magically become gigantic."

[image: Do you actually care about the size of node_modules?]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't install the separate components from the Material UI. The only way is to install the `@material-ui/core` directly.