# Importing only one component from Material UI

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui, components, stepper

need a Stepper component from somewhere and the only adequate one I found was the MUI one. But my app uses react-bootstrap and I don't have it. In this post ([Is it possible to install a package that contains only one component of Material-UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59468962/is-it-possible-to-install-a-package-that-contains-only-one-component-of-material) ) the guys have given a package where you can import only the component you need, but for some reason I am required to do `npm config set '@bit:registry' https://node.bit.dev` which I am not okay with since I want everyone to be able to just do an `npm install` without additional configuration. Is there a workaround around that and is it actually okay to install the whole MUI kit and import just the Stepper ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using ES6 modules and a bundler that supports tree-shaking ([webpack >= 2.x](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/), [parcel with a flag](https://en.parceljs.org/cli.html#enable-experimental-scope-hoisting/tree-shaking-support)) you can safely use named imports and still get an optimised bundle size automatically.

You can use path imports to avoid pulling in unused modules. For instance, use:

```js
import Stepper from '@material-ui/core/Stepper';
```

instead of

```js
import { Stepper } from '@material-ui/core';
```

Read more about minimizing bundle size [here](https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/)

---

Please, let me know if it works or not )