# Is there a way that I could extract TablePagination component from MUI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, pagination

I want to use only TablePagination component from MUI, is there a way that I could extract TablePagination files and keep them at a separate place, so that I don't have to install MUI in my react project?

I tried taking the files from node modules and using them, but I received errors.

Comment: Hello

Have you check this reference link it might be help you. 
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59468962/is-it-possible-to-install-a-package-that-contains-only-one-component-of-material#:~:text=The%20only%20way%20is%20to,material%2Dui%2Fcore%20directly.&text=You%20don't%20need%20to,just%20import%20one%20single%20component.

2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59468962/is-it-possible-to-install-a-package-that-contains-only-one-component-of-material

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to install a package that contains only one component of Material-UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59468962/is-it-possible-to-install-a-package-that-contains-only-one-component-of-material)

Answer (score 0):

you can install individual component of Material-UI.
you can use bit.dev collection,

[enter link description here](https://bit.dev/mui-org/material-ui)

Here is the Button component for example:
[enter link description here](https://bit.dev/mui-org/material-ui/button)